# Html table display of rows like: Picture - title - media player from a csv file

Tags: html, html-table, media, import-from-csv

I must say this is out of my expertise, and I need your help because I want to avoid **PHP**/**mysql**.

I tried this which worked best:

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("record-list.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>"; ?>
```

but it doesn't display the picture and this data in the cell: `<img src="audio/mainpic.jpg"/>`  do not work.

To simplify, I have the first column of my CSV that are pictures and this is the data inside : `audio/mainpic.jpg`
next columns are some text.
Last column is a path to an audio clip like: `audio/sound.mp3` and I'm searching to have a small media player displayed in the cell.

Am I dreaming?

Please help me out.

Comment: maybe add a sample line from the csv..

Comment: this is one line example:
audio/mainpic.jpg, 83944, eddie mitchell - midnight hour - LP,     audio/83944_audio.mp3

Comment: i could also use http://www.convertcsv.com  but i would prefer an automated solution, so i just need to update the csv to add new lines...

Comment: Does that image exist on your server?